# How to test ldap authentication from specific ldap master on Solaris client

Tags: linux, openldap

I have OpenDS LDAP running on Linux, which is two node master, sea-ldap.xx.yy.ss and phx-ldap.xx.yy.ss. There are Solaris clients, which gets authentication from these servers depend on client it located in Seattle or Phoenix

For Seattle clients --> uri ldaps://sea-ldap.xx.yy.ss/ ldaps://phx-ldap.xx.yy.ss/

For Phoenix clients --> uri ldaps://phx-ldap.xx.yy.ss/ ldaps://sea-ldap.xx.yy.ss/

We are having a switch upgrade, so all connectivity will go down from Seattle side. I want to check all servers, if they can get authication from Phoenix side, irrespective of their location.

On OpenLDAP linux client, I can run this command - ldapsearch -D cn=ldapadm,dc=xx,dc=yy,dc=xx -W -H ldaps://phx-ldap.xx.yy.ss/ -b "dc=xx,dc=yy,dc=yy," "cn=johnp"

I don't have lddapsearch on Solaris-10 client, what is other way to check ? With ldap, I only have ldapaddent , ldapclient & ldaplist

Thanks